# Is there concise notation for a combination of sets?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, notation, order-theory

Say I have three distinct ordered sets of real numbers $X_{1}$, $X_{2}$ and $X_{3}$. How can I concisely represent an ordered set $(X_{1},X_{2}) \, \cup \, (X_{1},X_{3}) \, \cup (X_{2},X_{3}) $ that basically contains all combinations of the sets (ideally not limited to $p = 3$ variables, but abstracted to $p$)?

Comment: What does $(X_1,X_2)\cup (X_1,X_3)\cup(X_2,X_3)$ mean?  I know that an ordered pair is defined in terms of sets, but I'm not sure if you are using that, or even if you are using such a definition of ordered pairs, there are different set-theoretical definitions of ordered-pairs so we have to guess which one you are referring to.

Comment: @Batominovski Say $X_{1} = (1,2,3)$, $X_{2} = (4,5,6)$, $X_{3} = (7,8,9)$. Then $(X_{1},X_{2}) = ((1,4),(2,5),(3,6))$, $(X_{1},X_{3})=((1,7),(2,8),(3,9))$, $(X_{2},X_{3}) = ((4,7),(5,8),(6,9))$. Then $(X_{1},X_{2}) \cup (X_{1},X_{3}) \cup (X_{2},X_{3}) = ((1,4),(2,5),(3,6), (1,7),(2,8),(3,9),(4,7),(5,8),(6,9))$.

Comment: One piece of notation you could use is the [Cartesian product of sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), $X\times Y$, the set of all ordered pairs $(x,y)$ where $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$.  You still need to define the *ordering* for the ordered pairs, ie. what makes $(x,y) \lt (s,t)$ when the Cartesian products are unioned together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are given several sorted lists of numbers $X_1,\ldots, X_n$. The lists are all of the same size $m$, the lists come in a specific enumerated order, and the elements within each list are also ordered (numerically).

I don't know of any existing notation for zipping sets like this, but you could potentially define a notation such as:

$$\bigoplus_{\{X_1\ldots X_n\}} \equiv \{\, \langle X_i[k], X_j[k]\rangle\, : 1\leq i < j \leq n,\; 1\leq k\leq  m\} $$

where here $X_i$ refers to the $i$th set in your specified order, and $X[k]$ refers to the $k$th element of an ordered list.

Then if you had a family $\mathcal{F}$ of unspecified sets, their zipper would be the set $\bigoplus_{\mathcal{F}}$.